# Textview over Imageview?

Tags: java, android, textview, batterylevel

In my main.xml i've got an Imageview styled like google now card. This imageview change image every time the battery change percentage. I also have a textview in which i write the battery level. What i want is write the battery level over the imageview so i can see it near the battery image. This is the main.xml part:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBatteryInfoimage" (this change with percentage)
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="image"
    android:background="@layout/background_card"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/level"         
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FB8A34"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    tools:ignore="SelectableText,SpUsage" />
```

The battery level is writing by java

```
TextView textViewliv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.level);
            textViewliv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Battery level: "+ "<small> <font color='#343434'>" + level + "%</font></small>"));
```

How can i do it?

Comment: use a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`

Comment: @David_D Raghunandan's comment is an advice, not a question. You better use a FrameLayout and place TextView after ImageView

Comment: Oh sorry i'm so tired today:). Ok but i can't use other layouts because my application change to much if i change layout.